# How do I perform multi-window operations on a non-combined group of windows in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar, window-manager

With multiple windows/instances of an application open and the taskbar buttons set to "Always combine, hide labels", I can <kbd>Shift+right-click</kbd>  the taskbar button for the window group to open a menu allowing me to

- "Cascade",
- "Show windows stacked",
- "Show windows side by side",
- "Restore all windows",
- "Minimize all windows", or
- "Close all windows".

With the taskbar buttons set to "Combine when taskbar is full" or "Never combine", when I <kbd>right-click</kbd>, <kbd>Shift + right-click</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl + right-click</kbd> either the button or the Aero preview for a window in the group I get a menu allowing me to perform window operations on just that one window rather than each window in the group.

When I have a non-combined group of windows in the taskbar, how would I cascade, stack, etc. that group of windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With windows ungrouped, you can right-click on the taskbar itself and select "show windows stacked/side by side/cascade windows". This will work with all windows currently shown. For instance, if you have two Notepads open, and an IE; you could minimize one Notepad, right-click the taskbar and click "Show Windows Side by Side" and it would set them up the same as if they were grouped.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but that's Microsoft's fault, not the respondent's.  It looks like this is about as close to XP's functionality as I'm going to get.  Thanks.